# Comparar dos arreglos para validar que días de la semana se ejecutara cierta acción

Tags: c#, array, matrices, visual

Estoy iniciando en la programación y me surge un problema en C#, tengo dos arreglos uno que se genera con una información de un dispositivo donde guarda:

```
char[] valores = diasAlimentacionLTA.ToCharArray(); //esto es igual a = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }
string[] diaSemana = new string[7] { "Dom", "Sab", "Vie", "Jue", "Mie", "Mar", "Lun"};
```

Donde cada 1 representa el día de la semana que se activará dicha rutina y el 0 día que se excluiría, por decir en este caso se activa los días:
Dom, Sab, Vie, Jue, Mie, Mar, y el lunes no estaría activo, como pudiera realizar este bucle y comparar ambos arreglos para imprimir día activo.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo con arrays como lo tienes diseñado, no necesitas comparar los arreglos. Recorres el arreglo que tiene los dias de la semana a través de un indice y lo que haces es evaluar si el valor que el array valores tiene en dicha posición es uno para imprimirlo

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        char[] valores = { '1', '1', '1', '1', '1','1', '0' };
        string[] diaSemana = new string[7] { "Dom", "Sab", "Vie", "Jue", "Mie", "Mar", "Lun"}; 
    
        for (int i = 0; i < diaSemana.Length; i++) {
            //El predicado (i < valores.Length) es para evitar errores por indice fuera de rango, en el caso que el arreglo valores tenga menos elementos que diaSemana
            if( (i < valores.Length) && (valores[i]=='1')) Console.WriteLine(diaSemana[i]);
        }
    }
}
```